# CursorRecyclerViewAdapter with Multiple Viewtypes

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-recyclerview

I'm using CursorRecyclerViewAdapter from [this code snippet](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59)

It works fine When I use Single Viewtype in recyclerview.But If i use multiple viewtypes I get crashes saying `int android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.mItemViewType null object reference`

I use the below code to extend `CursorRecyclerViewAdapter`

```
public class PostCursorAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1=1;
private static final int VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2=2;
private Integer viewtype=0;

public PostCursorAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor){
    super(context,cursor);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {
    PostItem postitem = PostItem.fromCursor(cursor);
    Log.d("PostItem",postitem.toString());
        int viewtype=1;

    if (postitem.isFromMe()==true){
       viewtype=1;
      }
     else {
       viewtype=2;
      }

    switch (viewtype) {

        case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1:
            ViewHolder_Type1 viewholder1 = (ViewHolder_Type1) holder;
            TextView mytimeView = (TextView) viewholder1.mytimeTextView;
            mytimeView.setText(postitem.getPostTime());
            TextView mymsgView = (TextView) viewholder1.mymessageTextView;
            mymsgView.setText(postitem.getPostMsg());
            break;

        case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2:
            ViewHolder_Type2 viewholder2 = (ViewHolder_Type2) holder;
            TextView timeView = (TextView) viewholder2.timeTextView;
            timeView.setText(postitem.getPostTime());
            TextView msgView = (TextView) viewholder2.messageTextView;
            msgView.setText(postitem.getPostMsg());
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;

    switch (viewType) {

        case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.mypost, parent, false);
            ViewHolder_Type1 vh1 = new ViewHolder_Type1(v);
            return vh1;

        case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.post, parent, false);
            ViewHolder_Type2 vh2 = new ViewHolder_Type2(v);
            return vh2;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return null;
}
public static class ViewHolder_Type1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mymessageTextView, mytimeTextView;
    public ViewHolder_Type1(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.mymessageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mymessageTextView);
        this.mytimeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mytimeTextView);
    }


}

public static class ViewHolder_Type2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView messageTextView, timeTextView;
    public ViewHolder_Type2(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.messageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        this.timeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
    }
}}
```

Comment: where do you assign the view types (i mean that a view has type of VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1 or VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2)???

Comment: @pskink within on `onBindViewHolder` I set viewtype `if (postitem.isFromMe()==true){
       viewtype=1;
      }
     else {
       viewtype=2;
      }`

Comment: please read the docs of `public int RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemViewType(int position)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I solved it

create a private Cursor and assign it

```
    public PostCursorAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor){
    super(context,cursor);
    mCursor=cursor;

}
```

Implement `getItemViewType`

```
 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position))
        {
            PostItem postItem=PostItem.fromCursor(mCursor);
            if (postItem.isFromMe())
            {
                return VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1;

            }
            else
            {
                return VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2;

            }
        }
    return 1;

}
```

Change `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {
    PostItem postitem = PostItem.fromCursor(cursor);

    switch (getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition())) {

        case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1:
            ViewHolder_Type1 viewholder1 = (ViewHolder_Type1) holder;
            TextView mytimeView = (TextView) viewholder1.mytimeTextView;
            mytimeView.setText(postitem.getPostTime());
            TextView mymsgView = (TextView) viewholder1.mymessageTextView;
            mymsgView.setText(postitem.getPostMsg());
            break;

        case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2:
            ViewHolder_Type2 viewholder2 = (ViewHolder_Type2) holder;
            TextView timeView = (TextView) viewholder2.timeTextView;
            timeView.setText(postitem.getPostTime());
            TextView msgView = (TextView) viewholder2.messageTextView;
            msgView.setText(postitem.getPostMsg());
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `getItemViewType()` seems incorrect. The `return 1` at the very end makes no sense and it should be replaced by real fallback, not to mention that there's high chance either `VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1` or `VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2` const equals to `1` too. So you should fallback to something with clear meaning like `VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_NONE` with unique value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (I think) is that RecyclerView does not have any clue that you have multiple View Types.

The solution could be to Override `getItemViewType`. However this could be tricky when you can only decide the viewType from the Cursor. If this is the case, the I suggest that you override `GetItemViewType` method inside `CursorRecyclerViewAdapter` class.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
    int viewType = cursor // somehow determine the viewType;
    return viewType;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should implement `getItemViewType` to return the proper ViewType for each position in the recycler view. See tutorial [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Implementing-a-Heterogenous-ListView).